# How to handle JMS-Session timeout using HornetQ?

Tags: java, tcp, jms, hornetq

can any one explain how to handle JMS-Session timeout.In my application am using Hornetq its working fine after sometime the error will getting( JMS-Session timeout) please help me.
public HornetQProducer() {

```
    try {
        ic = getInitialContext();

        cf = (ConnectionFactory) ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
        queue = new HornetQQueue("ExampleQueue");
        connection = cf.createConnection();
        logger.info("Connection object of HornetQ <<<>>>>>>>" + connection);
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        messageProducer = session.createProducer(queue);
        connection.start();
        logger.info("Message Producer HornetQ....." + messageProducer);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: When the exception happens? Please post the stack trace. Are you using durable session? Does it happens on receiving or sending messages?

Comment: Am using listner class when ever exception comes timeout happend.

Comment: Post the stack trace. It is hard to help you without it.

Comment: The code is OK. It shows how are you connecting to JMS provider. The fact that you can do it. But after that something wrong happens. *Stacktrace* can help to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Try to configure connection factory in HornetQ configuration file like this.

```
<connection-factory name="NettyConnectionFactory">
  <xa>false</xa>
  <connectors>
     <connector-ref connector-name="netty"/>
  </connectors>
  <entries>
     <entry name="/ConnectionFactory"/>
  </entries>
  <retry-interval>1000</retry-interval>
  <retry-interval-multiplier>1.0</retry-interval-multiplier>
  <reconnect-attempts>1</reconnect-attempts>
</connection-factory>
```

To handle JMS timeout try to work with JMSException.